# Android: How can I start a second app without the calling app being closed?

Tags: android, overlay

[image: Picture of the robot]

This robot has a user interface that is an app that runs on an Android operating system. I have created a simple web browser app (webview) that should only display a single web page where a customer can sign up for a trial at a gym. Once this app is launched from the robot's user interface, I cannot return to the robot's user interface after closing the Webview app. The standard app launcher of the Android OS appears, which the customer is not allowed to see.

Is there a way to open the Webview application so that the robot's user interface reappears after it has been closed? I was thinking of an overlay, for example, but I don't know if that's possible.

The customer should press a button on the user interface, then the Webview app opens and the customer can register for a trial training session at the gym. Afterwards, the webview should close (via an X-button) and return to the robot's user interface. (I cannot change anything in the source code of the user interface as the manufacturer locks it for changes. But I can call up apps from it).

Comment: This looks very relevant: https://developer.android.com/work/dpc/dedicated-devices/lock-task-mode

Comment: Perhaps you don't need a second app at all if you launch the webpage in a chrome custom tab? https://developer.chrome.com/docs/android/custom-tabs. This way you'll stay inside the originating app